# When I grag and drop the sprites it doubles. I have a strange construction of a file, so I don't understand how to fix it

Tags: python, pygame

This is how my main cycle looks:

```
while running:
global number
music_play()
if game_status == -1:
    rules()
if game_status == 0:
    menu()
if game_status == 0.5:
    choice()
if game_status == 1:
    level(number)


#   Limit to FPS
clock.tick(FPS)
#   Update the screen with what have been drawn
pygame.display.flip()
```

I have a problem working with a level()
This is the code:

```
def algorithm_level():
global lvl
global running
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #   When the mouse button is pressed, see if we are in contact with other sprites
        items_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, item_list, False)

        #   Set the list of items we are in contact with as the list of items being carried
        player.carry_item_list = items_hit_list

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        #   When we let up on the mouse, set the list of items we are carrying as empty
        player.carry_item_list = []

all_sprites_list.update()

def draw_level():
global lvl
global local_flag
global level_coordinates
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(lvl['background'], (800, 600)), (0, 0))
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(lvl['knapsack'], (500, 500)), (width - 500, height - 500))
#   The flag is used in order to generate the coordinates for the Items only once
if not local_flag:
    local_flag = True
    for i in range(lvl['items_number']):
        #   Create random coordinates 'i' times, 'i' is equal to the number of items on this level
        h, w, = random.randint(100, height), random.randint(10, width - 550)
        level_coordinates.append((w, h))
#   A cycle for drawing n Items
for n in range(lvl['items_number']):
    #   This represents an Item
    item = Item('images/level_pics/lvl' + str(number) + '_pics/item' + str(n + 1) + '.png', level_coordinates[n][0], level_coordinates[n][1])

    #   Set the location for the item
    item.rect.x = level_coordinates[n][0]
    item.rect.y = level_coordinates[n][1]

    #   Add the item to the list of objects
    item_list.add(item)
    all_sprites_list.add(item)


#   Draw all the sprites
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)


def level(number):
global lvl
lvl = levels[number - 1]
global game_status
algorithm_level()
draw_level()
```

So when I drag the object, it doubles and a copy stays on a previous position. I know that I should update a background to solve this but bc of a structure of a code I dont understand how to do this. I tried to put `creen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(lvl['background'], (800, 600)), (0, 0)) screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(lvl['knapsack'], (500, 500)), (width - 500, height - 500))` somewhere alse in different place but it hides the items then